# Characters hair faces shows my characters UV's (Textures) instead of solid blue color I'm attaching

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

Hello guys I'm making a character based on the book "Learning Blender Second Edition" and I'm on the stage where I need to put materials on my characters hair, eyebrows and eyes. Well I did it, but on rendered preview (Blender Render) I see that my characters hair, eyebrows and eyes objects faces individually has characters UV's attached... This is so weird... I thing I made a mess somewhere and I just cannot understand, because I'm new to Blender program and I don't know how the system works... I attached image for you guys, I hope it will help a lot.

[image: Faces showing different material attached than I'm trying to attach]

Comment: When texture repeats on all faces of the mesh likely UV map is made for each face individually and each face is scaled to be of UV texture space (e.g. if you select mesh in Edit mode and press U > Reset). Assign some seams, unwrap and refine your UV layout, I don't know if book covers that though

Comment: Thanks for reply! I did reset and removed any materials from hair and eyebrows, but somehow still I can see UV's added to my eyebrows and hair. Now they cover all texture properly, but I don't need those character body UV's on my hair, I just want to put solid blue color to them and it doesn't work at all it's still shows UV's added to my hair elements. It's so weird....

Comment: I just want to put blue color on my hair and that's it... But it doesn't work... It somehow shows me UV maps on my hair, but where I put them?... Shows no material on my hair object...

Comment: Blender Internal allows to see the texture on the mesh even if there's no material; selecting all mesh faces in Edit mode and choosing image in the UV editor is enough; on the other hand selecting all faces and removing any image should be enough to stop image from showing (by default it won't be rendered though). Internal uses faces textures assignment hence this work. Make sure you didn't add any texture to the material as well

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand how to remove Blender Internal assigned image... Searching everywhere for hours now, but I can't find nothing...

Comment: Select the object, enter Edit mode, select one face showing the texture, then select all mesh with Ctrl+L to select linked. In UV editor UV map should be shown on top of the image. Remove that image (X button next to its name) *while still having faces selected*. Example is here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58170/remove-texture-from-object though not explained properly why this happens